# Highcharts - hover event handling for tooltip throws exception

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-mvc, jsp, highcharts

Angular 2+ is used for new part of huge Spring MVC application where Highcharts is used.
Later, highcharts charting (angular-highcharts) is added to new components written in angular 2+ technology. 
The same Highcharts 6 version is used at both sides. (Originaly Highcharts 4 was used in legacy application).

In angular part charting works as expected, but in legacy application, charts are rendered with unexpected styles and an exception for hover event for tooltip:

```
zone.js:195 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hover' of undefined
    at e.markerAttribs (highcharts.js:306)
```

Angular attempts to handle event from legacy application.

How to ensure that Highcharts coexists in both parts of web application?
Without conflicts and doubled Highcharts loading.

==
update:
It is found that exception for tooltip rendering is thrown when legacy highcharts option are on.
Exception thrown:

```
highcharts.src.js:27770 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hover' of undefined
at object.markerAttribs (highcharts.src.js:27770)
highcharts.src.js:27770 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hover' of undefined
at object.markerAttribs (highcharts.src.js:27770)
```

highcharts.src.js:27770 => `states` is undefined in `seriesStateOptions = seriesMarkerOptions.states[state];`

Options:

```
Highcharts.theme = {
colors: ["#FFB900",
    "#FF9100",
    "#FF6900",
    "#FF4100",
    "#FF1900",
    "#FFB900",
    "#FF9100",
    "#FF6900",
    "#FF4100",
    "#FF1900",
    "#FFB900",
    "#FF9100",
    "#FF6900",
    "#FF4100",
    "#FF1900",
    "#FFB900",
    "#FF9100",
    "#FF6900",
    "#FF4100",
    "#FF1900",
    "#1C468E"
],
sandColors: [
    "#f45b5b",
    "#8085e9",
    "#8d4654",
    "#7798BF",
    "#aaeeee",
    "#ff0066",
    "#eeaaee",
    "#55BF3B",
    "#DF5353",
    "#7798BF",
    "#aaeeee"
],
darkColors: [
    "#DDDF0D",
    "#55BF3B",
    "#DF5353",
    "#7798BF",
    "#aaeeee",
    "#ff0066",
    "#eeaaee",
    "#55BF3B",
    "#DF5353",
    "#7798BF",
    "#aaeeee"
],
skiesColors: [
    "#514F78",
    "#42A07B",
    "#9B5E4A",
    "#72727F",
    "#1F949A",
    "#82914E",
    "#86777F",
    "#42A07B"
],
grayColors: [
    "#DDDF0D",
    "#7798BF",
    "#55BF3B",
    "#DF5353",
    "#aaeeee",
    "#ff0066",
    "#eeaaee",
    "#55BF3B",
    "#DF5353",
    "#7798BF",
    "#aaeeee"
],
chart: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderWidth: 0,
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    spacingTop: 0,
    spacingBottom: 0,
    spacingLeft: 0,
    spacingRight: 0,
    style: {
        fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
    }
},
title: {
    align: 'left',
    style: {
        color: '#000000',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '12px'
    }
},
subtitle: {
    align: 'left',
    style: {
        color: '#B1B1B1',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fontSize: '12px'
    }
},
xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: '#999999',
    tickColor: '#999999',
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: '#666666',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            fontSize: '12px'
        }
    },
    title: {
        style: {
            color: '#666666',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            fontSize: '12px'
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    alternateGridColor: null,
    minorTickInterval: null,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    gridLineColor: '#DEDEDE',
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickWidth: 0,
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: '#F2670C',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            fontSize: '12px'
        }
    },
    title: {
        style: {
            color: '#666666',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            fontSize: '12px'
        }
    },
    stackLabels: {
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '12px',
            color: '#F2670C'
        },
        formatter: function () {
            if (this.total != 0) {
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total, 0, ',', '.');
            }
        }
    }
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
    symbolPadding: 8,
    symbolWidth: 16,
    itemStyle: {
        color: '#333333',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fontSize: '11px',
        lineHeight: '11px'
    },
    itemHoverStyle: {
        color: '#F2670C'
    },
    itemHiddenStyle: {
        color: '#CCCCCC'
    }
},
labels: {
    style: {
        color: '#666666'
    }
},
tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderWidth: 2,
    style: {
        color: '#333333',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fontSize: '12px',
        lineHeight: '16px'
    }
},
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        marker: {
            lineColor: '#333333'
        },
        dataLabels: {
            color: '#CCCCCC'
        }
    },
    spline: {
        marker: {
            lineColor: '#333333'
        },
        dataLabels: {
            color: '#CCCCCC'
        }
    },
    scatter: {
        marker: {
            lineColor: '#333333'
        },
        dataLabels: {
            color: '#CCCCCC'
        }
    },
    column: {
        marker: {
            lineColor: '#333333'
        },
        dataLabels: {
            color: '#CCCCCC'
        }
    },        
},
    toolbar: {
        itemStyle: {
            color: '#CCCCCC'
        }
    },
    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 20],
                stops: [[0.4, '#606060'], [0.6, '#333333']]
            },
            borderColor: '#000000',
            symbolStroke: '#C0C0C0',
            hoverSymbolStroke: '#FFFFFF'
        }
    }
```

};

// Apply the theme
var highchartsOptions = Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);

Comment: There is no enough information to deduce what can cause the problem, so could you provide me with some code or minimal working example, where the problem occurs?

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question. I'm afraid I cannot produce minimal working example in reasonable time since it is spring-mvc application that loads angular components.

Comment: I made an example with random data basing on your code (but without Angular, only using native Highcharts), and unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce the problem. It looks like the line of code mentioned above tries to refer to undefined object of states. Are you sure that, all markers of series are visible? Maybe could you try to provide me with your data?

Comment: I'm reproducing the chase with column-basic chart from Highcharts examples, https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic .With default options chart works, tooltip is shown. When options from the above are set, the exception is thrown.

Comment: Sorry there was an error in copied options, I've copied changed versions:
there was no series element in version with error: series: {
            marker: {
                radius: 0,
                lineColor: null, // inherit from series
                symbol: 'circle',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        fillColor: null,
                        fillColor: null,
                        lineWidth: 2,
                        radius: 6
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs, because the `column` series doesn't have its own `marker` object, so you shouldn't set it as a default option (using setOptions). You need to delete this part of code:

```
marker: {
    lineColor: '#333333'
}
```

from `plotOptions.column` configuration which you are setting in your theme definition. Then it will work without errors.

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/sra1jg0k/